# OpenERP 7 hide delete icon in Many2many tree

Tags: xml, many-to-many, odoo

Anybody knows how to hide the delete icon in a many2many tree. 
I tried the delete="false" in the tree tag but this is not working (V7).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `delete = "0`" this how it work in my code:

```
    <field name="your_field_name">
       <tree   delete="0" >
          ...
          .;
          ..


    </field>
```

Comment: In OpenERP 7 create="0" or create="false" both work normally did you upgrade the module correctly.  try to make a mistake and see if your odoo is still running then you are doing something wrong. `<treee .....>` this should raise an error and stop odoo from running

Comment: Yes I've updated it correctly, when I change it to <treee I get an error.

Comment: It's in inherit on the field consume_lines from mrp.production

Comment: Try to update the list of fields o think your code is not being rendered from what is see. What version of openerp 7 you are using may be it's an old version that don't seport this.